# Symfony 3, linux: how to clear cache?

Tags: symfony, caching

How do I place myself in the Symfony folder with the command in order to clear the cache?
The only way I know to access the Symfony files is by typing:

```
gksudo nautilus /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

But after using this command the terminal window gets inactvie. I need to open another terminal window to do other actions.

I am running on Linux and Symfony 3.
The command I am trying to use to clear the cache is:

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

Otherwise, since I can open the Symfony files with the command above, is it safe to delete everything there is in `Symfony/var/cache/dev` ?

Comment: What system are you using? Is it some type of Cloud system?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu on my laptop. No Cloud system. Thanks

Comment: Why not open a `terminal` window as root user? Open a terminal window and then use `sudo` and your command? Also, where is your Symfony folder located? Is it under `/opt/lampp/htdocs/Symfony`?

Comment: I am already as a root user. The problem is that I need to place myself at the Symfony folder in the command but the Symfony folder is hidden (the path you said is correct). That is why I need to open the files on a window using gksudo nautilus /opt/lampp/htdocs.

Comment: Ah! it worked! Thanks! Even tough, it was invisible, I could just do cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/Symfony

Comment: Select the checkmark by may answer please.

Comment: I also updated my answer to include the proper path that you needed. Selecting the checkmark by the answer helps users to find the correct answer if they have the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new command to clear the cache in Symfony 3.3 is:

```
php bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup -e prod
```

Where `-e prod` is the environment, and can be either `-e prod` or `-e dev`. And yes it is safe to delete `var/cache` completely; that will delete all the cache.

---

EDIT #2 based on comments

Also, run the above command in the folder:

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs/Symfony
```

Comment: Thank you! Good to know the new comand but how do I place myself in the Symfony folder in oder to be able to use the command?  For now, I will be deleting by hand from the folder window.